# Behaviour of a sequence - how to fix this faulty proof?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, inequality

Today I am resurrecting an interesting past question. The original post sounded like

> $\{a_k\}_{k\geq 1}$ is a sequence of positive real numbers and
>   $$\left|\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{\sin(a_k x)}{k^2}\right|\leq\left|\tan(x)\right| $$
>   holds for any $x\in(-1,1)$. Show that $a_k=o(k^2)$.

My faulty solution was to divide both sides of the given inequality by $x$ and to consider the limit as $x\to 0^+$,
$$ \left|\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{a_k}{k^2}\right|\leq 1 $$
in order to deduce that $a_k=o(k^2)$. The HUGE issue is that the exchange of $\lim_{x\to 0^+}$ and $\sum_{k\geq 1}$ is completely unjustified, and I am struggling in showing that $\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{\text{sinc}(a_k x)}{k^2}$ is uniformly convergent. I am not even sure the hypothesis ensure such uniform convergence. So, for short,

> **How to fix this faulty proof?**

Is there some slick application of the dominated convergence theorem or of the Banach-Steinhaus theorem?

Comment: It seems that the positivity of the Laplace transform of $\text{sinc}$ allows to bypass the uniform convergence, which might fail to hold.

Comment: Haven't really looked below at the answer yet, but if your proof can be fixed, the result would be the much stronger $a_k\in o(k)$, which I think to be false by examples such as $a_k=k\pi/15$ or something similar.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: I don't think so, the convergence of $\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{a_k}{k^2}$ does not imply $a_k=o(k)$. You may have $a_k=k$ for any $k$ which is a power of two, for instance.

Comment: What definition of $o$ are you using? The definitions I know of require $\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{a_k}k=0$ or equivalently that $|a_k|\le ck$ for any $c>0$ and all sufficiently large $k$, not just "most" sufficiently large $k$.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: my definition agrees with yours. I am simply stating that $\left|\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{a_k}{k^2}\right|\leq 1$ *does not* imply $a_k=o(k)$. We may define $a_k$ as $\frac{1}{10}$ and re-define $a_{2^m}$ as $\frac{2^m}{10}$. Then $\left|\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{a_k}{k^2}\right|\leq 1$ but $a_k\not\in o(k)$.

Comment: Ah my bad, okay then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us discuss if this variant is sound. It is safe to state that for any $x\in(0,1)$
$$ \left|\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{\sin(a_k x)}{x k^2}\right|\leq\left|\frac{\tan x}{x}\right| $$
as well as
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\left|\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{\sin(a_k x)}{x k^2}\right|=\left|\lim_{x\to 0^+}\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{\sin(a_k x)}{x k^2}\right|\leq\lim_{x\to 0^+}\left|\frac{\tan x}{x}\right|=1.$$
Now $\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{\sin(a_k x)}{x k^2}=f(x)$ is a continuous function over any compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^+$ and $|f(x)|\leq\frac{\zeta(2)}{x}$.
 We are allowed to compute $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)$ through a convolution with an approximate identity, i.e. through
$$ \lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)=\lim_{M\to +\infty}\int_{0}^{+\infty}M e^{-Mx} f(x)\,dx. $$
This gives
$$ \lim_{x\to 0^+}\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{\sin(a_k x)}{xk^2} =\lim_{M\to +\infty}M\int_{0}^{+\infty}\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{\sin(a_k x)e^{-Mx}}{x k^2}\,dx=\lim_{M\to +\infty}\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{M\arctan\left(\frac{a_k}{M}\right)}{k^2}$$
and $\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{M\arctan\left(\frac{a_k}{M}\right)}{k^2}$ is an increasing function of the $M$-variable (as a sum of non-negative and increasing functions). This gives
$$ \lim_{x\to 0^+}\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{\sin(a_k x)}{x k^2} =\sup_{M}\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{M\arctan\left(\frac{a_k}{M}\right)}{k^2}.$$
Let us assume that for some positive constant $C$ the inequality $a_k\geq Ck^2$ holds infinite times, in particular for $a_{k_1},a_{k_2},\ldots,a_{k_H}$, and let us consider $M=2a_{k_H}$. Since $\arctan(x)\geq\frac{9x}{10}$ over $\left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right]$,

$$ \sup_{M}\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{M\arctan\left(\frac{a_k}{M}\right)}{k^2}\geq \sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{M\arctan\left(\frac{a_k}{M}\right)}{k^2}\geq \sum_{h=1 }^{H}\frac{M\arctan\left(\frac{a_{k_h}}{M}\right)}{k_h^2}\geq\frac{9}{10}\sum_{h=1}^{H}\frac{a_{k_h}}{k_h^2}\geq\frac{9}{10}CH.$$
By taking $H=\left\lfloor\frac{2}{C}\right\rfloor$ we deduce
$$ \lim_{x\to 0^+}\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{\sin(a_k x)}{x k^2}=\sup_{M}\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{M\arctan\left(\frac{a_k}{M}\right)}{k^2}\geq \frac{3}{2} $$
which contradicts the fact that the LHS is bounded by $1$ in absolute value.
 This proves that $a_k=o(k^2)$ as wanted.